# Find nearest pins on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have been using the javascript Google Maps API to construct the following map: http://springhillfarm.com.au/locations-map/ and now I would like to list the nearest 5 pins when a user searches their location in the search bar.

Try out entering a suburb like "North Epping" and the map will move around well using the following function:

```
$("#searchclick").click(function(){

    var address = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;

    var address = address + " Australia";

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var latitude2 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude2 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var relocate = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);
            map.setCenter(relocate);

            map.setZoom(12);

            } //when status is OK

        }); // geocode
    });
```

But now I really want it to return the closest 5 pins.

How possible is this in javascript?

Answer (score 6):

I notice in your production code - which I might add could/should be heavily optimised! - you have your location and a bunch of markers using the following:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.5759571, 143.8064523);
var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.7994512, 144.9643374), map: map, title:"Toothpicks, 720 Swanston Street Carlton 3052 VIC", icon:image });
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.9097004, 115.8485327), map: map, title:"Good Life Shop, Shop 7 Dog Swamp Shopping Centre, Yokine WA 6060", icon:image });
```

etc...

If you had those markers in an array, eg:

```
var markers = [ marker0, marker1, etc... ]
```

a simple approach would be to use a bit of pythagoras to get the distance between your current location and all the markers. Something like:

```
// make a new array of markers since you probably don't want to modify the existing array
var markersByDistance = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var marker = markers[i];

    // using pythagoras does not take into account curvature, 
    // but will work fine over small distances.
    // you can use more complicated trigonometry to 
    // take curvature into consideration
    var dx = myLatlng.longitude - marker.longitude;
    var dy = myLatlng.latitude - marker.latitude;
    var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    markersByDistance[ i ] = marker;
    markersByDistance[ i ].distance = distance;

}

// function to sort your data...
function sorter (a,b) { 
    return a.distance > b.distance ? 1 : -1;
}

// sort the array... now the first 5 elements should be your closest points.
markersByDistance.sort( sorter );
```

This all may be pointless since Google Maps API might do this natively for you.

Comment: Ok this looks good... I've set up my array and installed what you gave me: var markers = [marker0,marker1,marker2,marker3,etc...

Comment: but for some reason the code you have isn't working - is that because the array I made doesn't contain certain data I need to give it?

Comment: to see my code look here (in chrome): view-source:http://springhillfarm.com.au/locations-map/ 
Line 3579

Comment: You haven't done anything with the data in markersByDistance. Now that it has been created and sorted, you have to do something with it. You said 'return the closest 5 pins' - in theory they are the first 5 elements of the markersByDistance. What you do with them now is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it only makes sense to display 5 pins if a user searches - he might move the map and then he will still see only 5 pins...

Instead I would go for a different approach: if loading the complete set of pins (like now) is too slow, just send the Google Maps viewport to an AJAX script and let this script return all pins in the current viewport. You can then only draw the pins that are relevant for the current map. When a user searches for his location, the viewport changes (you zoom to the new location), you request the AJAX script and get all pins in this area. This makes it much simpler and more scalable.

Comment: by "show five pins" I really mean, return the closest so I can display their names in HTML...