# Nearest land mark in geometry

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, postgresql

I have a table called map_places with city or country information and corresponding geometry and many other info related to the city . my database system is PostGIS. My requirement is:

Input to my application will be geometry which may or many not be exact geometry stored in DB. I need to find the nearest City info from the table with the help of input geometry. this input is not submitted by the user it will be by the system .  Any help is highly appreciated.

Is there a nearest neighbor implementation in php available for this or SQL to handle this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257605/find-nearest-pins-on-google-map check this out.

Comment: What is the Spatial database system you are using ? is it SQL server 2008 or PostGIS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nearest land mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647353/nearest-land-mark)

Answer (score 1):

Here the row 'location' is coordinates of your item (integer or float).
$id - the id of needed item in your table 'map_places'. The result of this query will be ID of  item that  has the location nearest to location of item with id you have pass in to the query

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT T2.id, abs(T1.location-T2.location) as DIF
FROM  map_places T1, map_places T2
WHERE T1.id = $id AND T1.id<>T2.id
order by T1.id) as RES
WHERE DIF = (SELECT min(abs(T1.location-T2.location))
FROM  map_places T1, map_places T2
WHERE T1.id=$id AND T1.id<>T2.id)
```

Comment: Simple arithmetic will not suffice in general because the planet the places are located on is egg-shaped, and the places have different elevations.

Comment: T1 and T2  are aliases of map_places table  used to distinguish themselves in a self-join of the map_laces table